# Is there a way to return the data from a registry key value

Tags: java, eclipse, advapi32

I'm working on a program whereby one of its functions is to remove a file on the hard drive referenced through a windows registry value. I've been using Advapi32Util for searching for the file, however I couldn't find any way to return the data connected to the value.

Comment: [see this](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util) ... example 17 might be the one to use.

Comment: [Here are some more examples](https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-read-write-windows-registry-using-jna.html) you can try.